# How to inverse rotate a ray in a ray tracer from world space to object space

Tags: c#, vector-graphics, raytracing

I am currently working on a ray tracer implementation in c# and I am trying to rotate my ray invertly to the 3Dobject's rotatio for intersectionDetection, but I seem to be doing multiple things wrong here...

### my code:

```
static internal Ray TranformRay(Ray r, Vector3 objectLocation, Vector3 objectRotation, float objectScale)
{
         //reverse location tranformation
        Vector3 newOrigin = r.origin - objectLocation;

        //reverse rotation transformation
        objectRotation = -1* objectRotation;
        Matrix4x4 ReverseRotation = Matrix4x4.CreateFromYawPitchRoll(Computations.ToRadians(objectRotation.X), Computations.ToRadians(objectRotation.Y), Computations.ToRadians(objectRotation.Z));
        newOrigin = Vector3.Transform(newOrigin, ReverseRotation);
        Vector3 newDirection = Vector3.Normalize(Vector3.TransformNormal(r.direction, ReverseRotation));

        //reverse scale
        newDirection /= objectScale;

        return new Ray(newOrigin, newDirection);
    }
```

---

my Ray r is my current ray that needs to be transformed.
3D objects in my world have a location, rotation, scale.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to transform your ray from world-space to object space. You should then compute your object to world transform and call `Matrix4x4.Invert` to produce the inverse transform. Not all transforms are invertible, but normal affine transformations should be fine.

Edit:
You would typically produce the object to world transform by calling the Matrix4x4 Create Scale/rotation/translation methods and multiply the transforms together. I would also recommend using a quaternion for your rotation instead of euler angles. Quaternions should make it easier to apply multiple successive rotations.

Assuming your ray is origin and direction you would use `Vector3.Transform` to transform the origin and `Vector3.TransformNormal` to transform the direction. The later does not apply the translation portion of the matrix.

This assumes you are using System.Numerics library, but most vector libraries should have equivalent functions.